# Flutter http package works on iOS sim, but not on web dev

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

So I have this piece of my code that handle's some basic post authentication with a django/nginx backend, and when I'm dev testing it on the iOS simulator, it works fine. However, when I am testing it on Flutter web, I keep getting this error.

```
XMLHttpRequest error.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Code in question (the function: working connection, funny enough is working as expected)

```
  static Future<bool> login(String username, String password) async {
    final Uri url = Uri.parse(baseUri.toString() + "/api/login/");
    var data = jsonEncode({"username": username, "password": password});

    if (await workingConneciton()) {
      var response = await http.post(url, headers: baseHeader, body: data);
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(response.body);

      if (json.containsKey("token")) {
        await User.setToken(json["token"]! as String);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times when using an API with flutter  ang getting this type of error, adding `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` to the header might fix the issue